# Basics of conversion of Not nullable to Nullable type

Tags: c#-3.0

What is the basics of conversion of Not Nullable type to Nullable type?

What happens inside CLR ?

is value type is internally converted to reference type?

```
int i = 100;

and int ? i = 7?
```

is both are value type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this to see that the `int?` is a value type:

```
class Program
{
    static int? nullInt;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        nullInt = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} + 3 != {1}", nullInt, DoMath(nullInt , 3).ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} * 3 = {1}" , nullInt , DoMultiply(nullInt , 3).ToString()));

        nullInt = null;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} + 3 != {1}" , nullInt , DoMath(nullInt , 3).ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} * 3 = {1}" , nullInt , DoMultiply(nullInt , 3).ToString()));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int? DoMath(int? x , int y)
    {
        if (x.HasValue)
        {
            return (++x) + y;
        }
        else
            return y;
    }

    static int DoMultiply(int? x , int y)
    {
        if (x.HasValue)
        {
            return (int)x * y;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

I have found these to be very interesting and makes for some clever uses.

What *`?`* does is create a nullable reference to an otherwise non-nullable value type. It is like having a pointer that can be checked - `HasValue` (a boolean value)? Nice thing about the `Nullable< T >` is that the `Value` property does not need to be cast to it's original type - that work is done for you inside the nullable struct.

Answer (score 2):

An `int?` is the same as [`Nullable<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) which is a struct, i.e. a value type. There are no conversions to reference types here.

Here's the definition of Nullable from MSDN:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct, new()
```

Answer (score 1):

`int? i` is just shorthand for [`System.Nullable <int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) `i`.  Both are indeed value types.